# How to get the namespace name in the c++ code

Tags: c++

I'd like to print for a debug reasons the namespace of the variable/function it is defined in. I'm trying to use the *define* directive:

```
#include <iostream>

#define NS Static
#define MAKESTRING(x) #x

namespace NS {
  int global_x = 8;
  void print_global_x() {

    //print global_x here:
    //std::cout << NS << ": " << global_x << std::endl;
    std::cout << MAKESTRING(NS) << "::global_x: " << global_x << std::endl;
  }
}
```

but at the *#1* line I'm getting *a namespace name is not allowed* error while with the second approach (line *#2*) I'm getting just `NS::global_x: 8` instead of `Static::global_x: 8`

How can I correct the code to get the desired result?

Comment: What is `#define NS Static` for?

Comment: "I'm getting just `NS::global_x: 8`" Is that not correct?  Why do you desire `global_x::global_x: 8`?

Comment: @DrewDormann Sorry I've corrected my answer. The expected result should be `Static::global_x: 8`.

Comment: `#define MAKESTRING_HELPER(x) #x` and then `#define MAKESTRING(x) MAKESTRING_HELPER(x)`

Comment: @VladFeinstein It's just a simple _define_ instruction. I'm defining the `NS` as a shortcut of the `Static` string to use further in the code wherever I'd like to use the `Static` namespace.

Comment: @Eljay. Thx friend. That's what I was looking for! Can You please explain me HOW does it work (I'm a beginner in the topic...)?

Comment: The two-step macro is needed because of the order of expansion for token replacement.  You want NS to become Static, but the NS *argument* to the macro is not expanded (hence the undesired behavior in your bug).  Passing it to the helper macro allows it to be token substituted, which does what is wanted.  If a non-macro was passed in, there is no token substitution, so passing to the helper is a benign no-op.